# Forum module : can i load the forum into an iframe?

Tags: forum

How can I go about making the forum load into an iframe so I can maintain the main site's header and footer sections?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't really EE specific - you'd load the forum in an iframe like you'd load anything else in an iframe.

That said - loading it in an iframe isn't a good idea. If you want to use your global header and footer (embeds/snippets?) in the forum then run your forum through the regular template engine using the {exp:forum} tag. More info about that here:

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/forum/other_features.html

That way you can have a template group called "forum.group" for instance, with an index.html in it which has:

```
{embed="embeds/global_header"}
{exp:forum}
{sn_global_footer}
```

And voila, you have your global header / footer code around the forum. Then you'll need to dive into the forum global header and footer templates and remove some html there of course to make it work properly.

Comment: Or your forum header/footer templates can call your embeds.